# Netezza SQL syntax to convert numeric YYYYMMDD format into date

Tags: sql, netezza

We have a Netezza table that contains dates stored in a numeric YYYYMMDD format (eg 20090731).

What is the best Netezza syntax to use to convert this into date format?

eg

```
SELECT somefunction(20090731) as NZDATE
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to convert number to date would be

```
select  date(to_char(20090731,'99999999')) as Number_As_DATE;
```

Comment: select to_date(20090731,'YYYYMMDD') as Number_As_DATE;

Answer (score 6):

You can use this one as it's the best one.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20090731','YYYYMMDD') as NZDATE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
to_date (sk_dim_time ,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 1):

My efforts were thwarted originally due to invalid dates. The code bellow does work as long as you wrap it in a statement to catch bad dates.

```
select  to_date(substring(20090731 from 1 for 8),'YYYYMMDD') as NZDATE
```

Obviously `20090731` should be replaced with the name of the numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date(20090731,'YYYYMMDD') as Number_As_DATE
```

This will work without converting to char.

Comment: You answered this 7 years later with the same answer posted 2 other times?